Saving pretrained random forest model for probability predictions in Google Earth Engine
I'm trying to export a pre-trained random forest model as an asset in Google Earth Engine, and then load it back in to predict on new data. The model is trained for binary classification, and I'd like to predict probabilities of these classes for the new data. This works fine when I use the model without saving it as an asset, but when I try to save it as an asset and then reload, I get this export error:
Error: SmileRandomForest cannot be exported with PROBABILITY mode. (Error code: 3)
The relevant parts of my code are here:
prob_classifier = (
    ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10)
    .setOutputMode("PROBABILITY")
    .train(
        features=training_samples,
        classProperty="flooded_mask",
        inputProperties=FLOOD_INPUT_PROPERTIES,
    )
)

ee.batch.Export.classifier.toAsset(
    classifier=prob_classifier,
    assetId=FLOOD_MODEL_ASSET_ID,
)


regressor = ee.Classifier.load(FLOOD_MODEL_ASSET_ID)
classified_image = image_to_classify.select(FLOOD_INPUT_PROPERTIES).classify(regressor)

My understanding based on Noel Gorelick's answer on this other Stack GIS post is that I may need to export the decision trees as an asset, load those back in, and use 'raw' to compute the probability myself, e.g.:
classifier = (
    ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10)
    .train(
        features=training_samples,
        classProperty="flooded_mask",
        inputProperties=FLOOD_INPUT_PROPERTIES,
    )
)
trees = ee.List(ee.Dictionary(classifier.explain()).get('trees'))

dummy = ee.Feature()        
col = ee.FeatureCollection(trees.map(function(x){return dummy.set('tree',x)}))
Export.table.toAsset(col,'save_classifier',AssetName)

# load classifier
trees = ee.FeatureCollection(AssetName).aggregate_array('tree')
classifier = ee.Classifier.decisionTreeEnsemble('trees').setOutputMode("raw")

result = image.classify(classifier)
max = result.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode())
prob = result.eq(max).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())

Is there no more efficient way to tackle this?
